# I want to reverse a text using these functions but i dont know what went wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void reverse_Text(char* str);

int main()
{   
    int i, j, Text, revText;
    const int [arrSize] = 101;
    char Text[arrSize], revText[arrSize]; 

    cout << "Please enter a sentence: ";
    cin >> Text;

    reverse_Text(Text);

    cout << "The reversed text is " << Text << endl;
    return 0;

}

int reverse_Text(char ori_str, char rev_str)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(j = strlen(ori_str)-i, j >= 0, j--){
        rev_str[i] = ori_str[j];
        rev_str[i+1] = '0';
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to find the error, im still a newbie in coding, it says that text and revtext are not declared, i cant find the next error when there is already an error at the top

Comment: `const int [arrSize] = 101;` should be `const int arrSize = 101;` to begin with.

Comment: You should use a debugger to identify what's going wrong in your code.

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual errors you get. The compiler should be complaining about a redefinition of Text and revText, for example.

Comment: Your function doesn't match the prototype either. 
Also, why use `char []` in c++? Use `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

```
int reverse_Text(char ori_str, char rev_str)
```

This function takes two characters as parameters. You actually need to pass the addresses of the characters.

```
int reverse_Text(const char* ori_str, char* rev_str)
```

Notice that I've declared the first parameter as `const`. This tells the compiler that the original string is not supposed to be changed. The compiler will then generate an error if any code inside the function tries to modify any character in the original string.

You will need to pass both parameters, not just one, when you call the function.

```
reverse_Text(Text, revText);
```

This is actually passing the address of the first character in each string.